# how to fix "your account is locked. please contact admin" issue in postgresql when login

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm new to PostgreSQL.I'm using postgreSQL locally. I used it last time without any issues. Now, when I try login with my login credentials it shows the account is locked message all the time.
[image]

Comment: This needs more information: 1) How did you install Postgres? 2) Postgres version? 3) Who setup pgAdmin? 4) Can you log into the server via `psql`. This by the way is an pgAdmin issue not a Postgres one.

Comment: 1. I followed this https://www.tecmint.com/install-postgresql-and-pgadmin-in-ubuntu/
 blog to install postgresql and pgadmin4.
2). Postgres version psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-1.pgdg20.04+1)
 3. I did setup the pgadmin using following command. sudo apt install pgadmin4 . i setup the initial mail and password.

 4). I think i can log in psql. if i'm not wrong.
```
sudo su - postgres
[sudo] password for gowtham: 
postgres@Gowtham-PC:~$ psql

postgres=# CREATE USER tecmint WITH PASSWORD 'securep@wd';
ERROR:  role "tecmint" already exists
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the pgadmin [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/restore_locked_user.html) there are two ways to unlock the user.

**1.** Updating SQLite DB (pgAdmin4.db):

> Locate the pgAdmin4.db file and open it using any DB Browser (or DB Browser for SQLite)
>
> After opening the DB file, head towards ‘Execute SQL’ section.
> Run below query :

```
UPDATE USER SET LOCKED = false, LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 0 WHERE USERNAME = <YOUR_EMAIL_ID>
```

And make sure the query changes are committed.

**2.** Increase the MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS in the pgadmin [configuration](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html) file config.py or preferably add a line in config_local.py

```
MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 5
```

Comment: the file located at `/var/lib/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.db`

Comment: How can I open it in a docker container?

Answer (score 2):

As @alfredo138923 explains, you should find pgadmin4.db on your system and run a query to update the USER attempts and unlock the application for the specific user account.

But the correct SQL query must be fixed. The query parameter value **must use single quotes**, otherwise an error will be returned.

```
UPDATE USER SET LOCKED = false, LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 0 WHERE USERNAME = '<YOUR_EMAIL>'
```

An example on the shell command line might be (i use Ubuntu 20.04)*:

```
sqlite3 pgadmin4.db "UPDATE USER SET LOCKED = false, LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 0 WHERE USERNAME = 'user.name@domain.com';" ".exit"
```

*Before using sqlite3 from the command line, you need to install it as below.

```
apt-get install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Solve this Issue

First Locate the  pgAdmin4.db  in Ubuntu 20.04  you find following path

cd /var/lib/pgadmin

then run the following command

sqlite3 pgadmin4.db
there might be two files but choose the file of heavy size

SQLite  will be opened

now than run the command
UPDATE USER SET LOCKED = false, LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 0 WHERE USERNAME = '<YOUR_EMAIL>'

now you can login

Answer (score -3):

[image]**Under Ubuntu 20.4**
you must find the file vi /usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py
change the MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS =0
restart your server
systemctl restart postgresql
**OR** stop it then start it again
systemctl stop postgresql
systemctl start postgresql

Comment: This may explain how to prevent lock-outs in the future, but doesn't say how to unlock a user that's already locked out. And do you really need to restart Postgres when changing pgAdmin configuration?